# DRY up context and subject repetition while testing many states

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've finally taken the plunge and I'm learning RSpec after years of barely doing any automated testing.

I'm testing a model with 18 possible state combinations. Currently, my spec looks something like this simplified example (note that `create` comes from `factory_girl`):

```
describe MyModel do
  context 'in unapproved state' do
    context 'with guest account' do
      subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :unapproved, :guest) }

      describe '#method_a' do
        it { ... }
      end

      describe '#method_b' do
        it { ... }
      end
    end

    context 'with full account' do
      subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :unapproved, :full) }

      describe '#method_a' do
        it { ... }
      end

      describe '#method_b' do
        it { ... }
      end
    end
  end

  context 'in approved state' do
    context 'with guest account' do
      subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :approved, :guest) }

      describe '#method_a' do
        it { ... }
      end

      describe '#method_b' do
        it { ... }
      end
    end

    context 'with full account' do
      subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :approved, :full) }

      describe '#method_a' do
        it { ... }
      end

      describe '#method_b' do
        it { ... }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works great and I'm (mostly) happy with it. However, I've been doing a lot of reading on RSpec best practices and it appeears I should probably put all my `describe`s at the outermost level and nest `context`s inside them (opposite of what I have above).

Putting `describe`s at the outermost level makes perfect sense to me as it groups together the components of your class (the things you're actually testing). My example above would become:

```
describe MyModel do
  describe '#method_a' do
    context 'in unapproved state' do
      context 'with guest account' do
        subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :unapproved, :guest) }
        it { ... }
      end

      context 'with full account' do
        subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :unapproved, :full) }
        it { ... }
      end
    end

    context 'in approved state' do
      context 'with guest account' do
        subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :approved, :guest) }
        it { ... }
      end

      context 'with full account' do
        subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :approved, :full) }
        it { ... }
      end
    end
  end

  describe '#method_a' do
    context 'in unapproved state' do
      context 'with guest account' do
        subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :unapproved, :guest) }
        it { ... }
      end

      context 'with full account' do
        subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :unapproved, :full) }
        it { ... }
      end
    end

    context 'in approved state' do
      context 'with guest account' do
        subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :approved, :guest) }
        it { ... }
      end

      context 'with full account' do
        subject { build_stubbed(:my_model, :approved, :full) }
        it { ... }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is cool and I think it makes my spec easier to read and to navigate. However, there's now a lot of repetition with the contexts and subjects.

What's a good way to reduce the repetition in this scenario?

Comment: Got the same on a model with a state column, and noticed the same thing about specs "worflow". I think tests tells something here, kinda "you should extract that approved / unapproved state somewhere else" (subclass ? or a method that return a state object ?)